# DLRS Rollup not working with tertiary criteria

Tags: roll-up-summary, dlrs

I learned a new requirement that now the rollups must be filtered on a third criteria. (This will mean creating 62 new fields to capture the rollups... but I digress).  So I added this new, tertiary criteria.

However, it's not working. I have checked and re-checked and re-re-checked.  New criteria in circled in red on the image.  Prior to adding the new criteria, the rollup was working across all opptys that met the stage and competing criteria.

[image]

I ran a query with those criteria to ensure there are records that meet them, and that I wasn't missing something.

[image]

Comment: In theory it should be functionally equivalent, but why use `IN` instead of `=`? Also, check FLS that you have read access to that field.

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianLarson.  I originally had = 'Aerosol Fill'. Tried 'in' as a desperation move. 

Thanks for the tip - all criteria fields are visible to all profiles.

Comment: Yeah all looks in order to me so it's the only thing I could think of. You might try switching to some parameter which is obviously true like `Id != null` so you can verify if it *ever* works with a third criterion. I admit I'm stumped.

Comment: I tried that and no dice. I'm not sure what the hiccup is. I literally took an existing, functional rollup and added one criteria, and changed the destination field for the calculated rollup value.

Answer (score 0):

Chalk this one up to "wrong field". Ammonia, Aerosol, Antimony... :/